# Cómo puedo darle un ancho a las columnas

Tags: jtable

tengo un problema.

Intentes darle un ancho a las columnas, intente con el siguiente métodos:

> tabla.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(40);

Este me mando un error y desaparecia la tabla de mi ventana.

**El de abajo es mi código donde creo mi tabla**

private void crearTabla(){

**Codigo:**

```
    DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();        
    JTable tabla = new JTable(){
        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
            return false;
        }
    };        

    tabla.setBounds(20, 90, 800, 350);      
    tabla.setModel(modelo);
    tabla.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);        
    JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(tabla);    
    scroll.setBounds(20, 90, 650, 350);
    scroll.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);    
    scroll.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);                

    modelo.addColumn("ID");
    modelo.addColumn("Nombre");
    modelo.addColumn("Fecha Nacimiento");
    modelo.addColumn("Genero");
    modelo.addColumn("Salario");
    modelo.addColumn("Calle");
    modelo.addColumn("Colonia");
    modelo.addColumn("Numero");
    modelo.addColumn("Usuario");
    modelo.addColumn("Contraseña");

    

    AgregarEmpleado cargaTabla = new AgregarEmpleado();         
    cargaTabla.cargaDatosTabla(modelo);

    
    this.add(scroll);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Debería quedar así:

```
DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();
JTable tabla = new JTable(modelo);
tabla.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(80);
JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(tabla);
```

> Esto es el que modifica la anchura, consejo ponle medida a todas las columnas para que veas como funciona, luego solo a los que creas necesarios.
> Yo lo declaro dentro de una clase, no recomiendo ponerlo como método.